# Is it possible to read a pdf form produced by itextsharp with IText java?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

Is it possible to read a pdf form produced by itextsharp with IText java ?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String src = "D:\\Doc\\Filled_PDF_Form.pdf";
    PdfReader reader;
    try {
        reader = new PdfReader(src);
        AcroFields fields= reader.getAcroFields();

        Set<String> fieldKeys = fields.getFields().keySet();
        for(String itemKey : fieldKeys){
            System.out.println(itemKey + ": " + fields.getField(itemKey));
        }
        reader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

}
```

**The fields return as null**

Comment: Did you know that iTextSharp is the old name and that is currently just called "iText"?

Comment: Did you know that iText Java and iText .NET are made by the same team, and that they (we) take great efforts to make sure that the product works identical on both platforms?

Comment: I am removing the redundant pdfbox tag

Comment: yes i know, but while reading a pdf  which was produced by itextsharp  returns acrofields as null

Comment: The same thing would happen if the pdf had been created using iText Java with the same (equivalent) Java code.

Comment: Is there a way that i could read the fields values ? (i am trying to read from a fillable PDF)

Comment: Is there a way that i could read the fields values with itext ? (i am trying to read from a fillable PDF)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is : **Yes**

You can read and write any pdf which is produced with *itextsharp* or any different tools by using *IText* library. Because it would be a file with .pdf extension and this library allows to read and write pdf.

Here is an example of reading pdf in IText:

```
public class PDFReadExample {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    try {
    //Create PdfReader instance.
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("D:\\itextsharp\\testFile.pdf");    

    //Get the number of pages in pdf.
    int pages = pdfReader.getNumberOfPages(); 

    //Iterate the pdf through pages.
    for(int i=1; i<=pages; i++) { 
      //Extract the page content using PdfTextExtractor.
      String pageContent = 
        PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(pdfReader, i);

      //Print the page content on console.
      System.out.println("Content on Page "
                          + i + ": " + pageContent);
      }

      //Close the PdfReader.
      pdfReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

as a consequence, you will have a pdf file generated with itextsharp and located in `D:\\itextsharp`.

Comment: But the problem is i am unable to read the field values of the fillable PDF.

Comment: can you please share your code where you got problem by editing your question?

Comment: your code works actually, please try with this fillable pdf http://foersom.com/net/HowTo/data/OoPdfFormExample.pdf

Comment: the problem about having null set is probably beacuse of pdf that you have

Comment: yes but the pdf which i received from client doesn't work.. may be it has removed the acro properties ?

Is there a way that i could read the fields values with itext ? (i am trying to read from a fillable PDF)

Comment: This means that the pdf from the client is the issue. If you can share it, we're may help analyzing it.

Comment: Sorry, that's confidential